# How can I use either Runtime.exec() or ProcessBuilder to open google chrome through its pathname?

Tags: java, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I am writing a java code that has the purpose of opening a URL on youtube using Google Chrome but I have been unsuccessful in understanding either method. Here is my current attempt at it.

```
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class processTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
    commands.add("cd C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application");
    commands.add("chrome.exe youtube.com");
    ProcessBuilder executeCommands = new ProcessBuilder( "C:/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe", "cd C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application", "chrome.exe youtube.com");
    }
}
```

It compiles OK, but nothing happens when I run it. What is the deal?

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc for the `ProcessBuilder` constructor?  It accepts a _single_ command and its arguments, not a series of commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Jim Garrison, `ProcessBuilder`'s constructor only executes a single command. And you do not need to navigate through the directories to reach the executable.

Two possible solutions for your problem (Valid for my Windows 7, be sure to replace your Chrome path if neccesary)

With `ProcessBuilder` using constructor with two parameters: command, argument (to be passed to command)

```
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb =
           new ProcessBuilder(
              "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", 
              "youtube.com");

        pb.start();

        System.out.println("Google Chrome launched!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With `Runtime` using method `exec` with one parameter, a String array. First element is the command, following elements are used as arguments for such command.

```
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
          new String[]{"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", 
                       "youtube.com"});

        System.out.println("Google Chrome launched!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you shoule invoke start method to execute the operation, like this:

```
ProcessBuilder executeCommands = new ProcessBuilder( "C:/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe", "cd C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application", "chrome.exe youtube.com");
executeCommands.start();
```

Comment: Have you tested it? I've tried your code and nothing happens.